# General linear group of a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces, lie-groups

I am reading a text on *Lie groups*.

There is a whole chapter devoted to the *group of invertible real or complex matrices of degree $n$*, which are called the ***general linear groups*** (complex and real).

Further in the text, there is a reference to a *general linear group of a vector space*, in general. What is meant exactly by that? And why do we use the same terminology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of bijective linear maps from a finite-dimensional vectorspace $V$ to itself is isomorphic (as a group) to the group of invertible $n\times n$ matrices, where $n$ is the dimension of the vectorspace (to get an isomorphism, just pick a basis).

The first one is what is meant by the general linear group of a vectorspace.

Comment: Well, to be technical, you only need to pick a basis to determine the components of the matrix representing the isomorphism.

Comment: @AlexNelson I am not sure what you mean. Picking a basis is what you need to get a matrix from a bijective linear map, which is what I meant by the remark.