# What is the meaning of $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't really know the proper names for these spaces so I can't search for this on google, and the book we are using just assumes we know what these things mean.

What are these spaces similar to?  What are some simple examples of these spaces?  What makes them unique or different from other spaces (what are their special properties)?

Comment: General linear group and special linear group: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#General_linear_group_of_a_vector_space

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534602/general-linear-group-of-a-vector-space

Comment: @EthanBolker: these are the Lie algebras, not the groups.

Comment: @Ethan Bolker.  I pretty sure that's not the same thing.  The objects I'm referring are denoted by this special gothic lower-case script.

Comment: @carmichael561  Yes, thanks. OP take note.

Comment: So from what I gathered, $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ represents the Lie alg. whose elements are linear endomorphisms from a vec. sp. $V$ to itself (i.e. $n \times n$ matrices). And the def'n of $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ is similar, but these matrices have trace zero.

Comment: @NażysławZbyłutowicz : this is correct. In general, if $G$ is a Lie group (a group which is a differentiable manifold, with smooth multiplication and inverse) then $\mathfrak g$ is the tangent space at $e$. Since $G = GL(V)$ is dense in $End(V)$ this gives you $\mathfrak{gl}(V) = End(V)$. For $G = SL(V)$ you need to play a bit with the equation $A^t A = \text{I}_n$.

Answer (score 1):

They are the coordinate-free analogues of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$, the Lie algebra of $n \times n$ matrices, and $\mathfrak{sl}_n$, the Lie algebra of traceless $n \times n$ matrices. Coordinate-free definitions tend to be nice, since they reassure you that there is nothing tricky hiding in amongst all the matrix multiplication nonsense: everything still works on the level of abstract linear operators.

For any vector space $V$, define $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ to be the Lie algebra whose vector space is $\mathrm{End}(V)$, the space of all linear maps $V \to V$, with Lie bracket given by the commutator: for any $f, g \in \mathrm{End}(V)$, set $[f, g] = fg - gf$.

The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(V)$ is defined similarly, however the underlying vector space is *traceless* linear operators:
$$ \mathfrak{sl}(V) = \{f \in \mathrm{End}(V) \mid \mathrm{tr}(f) = 0 \}$$
and again the Lie bracket is given by the commutator. You can see that if $f, g \in \mathfrak{sl}(V)$, then $\mathrm{tr}(fg - gf) = \mathrm{tr}(fg) - \mathrm{tr}(gf) = 0$, and so the commutator does indeed give a Lie bracket on this space.

Answer (score 0):

Let $K$ be a field. Identifying the $K$-vector space $V$ with $K^n$ we have the Lie algebras
$$
\mathfrak{gl}(V)\cong \mathfrak{gl}_n(K)=M_n(K)
$$

$$
\mathfrak{sl}(V)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)=\{ A \in M_n(K) \mid tr(A)=0\},
$$
with the Lie bracket $[A,B]:=AB-BA$. They are the Lie algebras of the linear Lie groups $GL_n(K)$ and $SL_n(K)$. Assume that $K$ has characteristic zero. Then
$\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ is a *simple* Lie algebra, and $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ is a *reductive* Lie algebra. Both are important in algebra, geometry, phasics and other areas.